# Recurrence Relation in Two Variables

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Does anyone have any hints on solving the following recurrence relation: 
$$ 
f(m,n) = b f(m,n-1) + c f(n,m-1) \\
f(0,n) = b^n \\
f(m,0) = c^m
$$
where $ b$ and $c $ are positive real numbers.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The last f on the RHS of the first identity is f(m-1,n)?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Prove by induction that $$f(m, n) = {m + n \choose m}c^mb^n$$
This equality can be seen after a couple of function evaluations have been written down. For example $$f(0, 0)=1, f(1, 0)=c, f(0, 1)=b, f(2, 0)=c^2, f(1, 1)=2cb, f(0, 2)=b^2,  \dots$$